# Check type of object against a string representation of a type object in Python

Tags: python, types

In Python code, would like to check the type of a variable against a provided type that I receive as a string (e.g., 'int', 'str', 'list'). I would like to check if my current object is castable to or is an instance of the provided string argument, including handling for inheritance (so basically, I would like to use isinstance). I know you can get the string representation of a built-in type, but is there a way to go the other way around and build a type object from its name?

```
str_type = 'str'
my_obj = "hello world"
#[get from str_type to type object]
same_type = isinstance(my_obj, type)
```

Comment: You could build the mapping `{"str": str, "int": int, ...}`. Otherwise you're going to end up using `eval`, which is unsafe on user input.

Comment: You could use [**`literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also see if you can instantiate the object based on a string type by first converting the string type using pydoc.locate:

https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/pydoc.html